# 3 element array for java, i need help understanding it

Tags: java, arrays

Hi can someone explain to me what is the question asking? i don't quite get what is 3 element array in java. This is the full question.

> Declare a 3-element array of characters charArr, and initialize the values to `'*'`

Comment: It's an array that has 3 elements - element 0, element 1 and element 2.

Comment: It means that you need to create array of length 3 and place there elements mentioned in question. Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are requested to create an array of type `char` with 3 elements and initialize it like this:

```
char[] myCharArray = new char[] {'*', '*', '*' };
```

UPDATE: Or even shorter:

```
char[] myCharArray = {'*', '*', '*' }; // or {'\'', '*', '\'' }
```

Comment: It could also mean `{'\'', '*', '\''}`. Also in this case you don't need `new char[]` part.